# Manipulating Nested data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Im working on a component that handles labels and child labels. I've figured out the data structure (i think) and how to render the component using existing data.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-labels-7vfkb?file=/example.js:292-330

However, im completely stuck on how I should manipulate the data.

For example, I need to be able to rearrange rows up and down.
I need to be able to delete a specific row and all its children, I need to add to children, etc.

I'm not entirely sure how to track each rows position within the data structure in order to perform these operations. I don't want to rely on the label text because text could match.

I assume that as I render out the components, there' some piece of information regarding positioning I can attach to the delete/add/up and down buttons, just not sure what or how exactly.

Data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    label: "Label: 1",
    children: [
      {
        label: "Label: 1.1",
        children: [
          {
            label: "Label: 1.1.1",
            children: [{ label: "Label: 1.1.2" }, { label: "Label: 1.1.3" }]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
```

Comment: this is javascript / react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I want to suggest to use a package like [react-sortable-tree](https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree). This is just one example of many for implementations solving your problem. I think, even your data has already the perfect structure as input data for this package.

If you have a good reason to implement this by yourself, you should keep the requirements as simple as possible because this can become really time consuming and difficult.

Break things down into small pieces and better write some tests.

You need to add event handlers for your data manipulation and you already mentioned what to do:

- handleRowUp
- handleRowDown
- handleDeleteRow
- handleAddRow

I suppose you would end up with a number of further helper functions to keep everything maintainable.

- addChild
- removeChild
- changeRowHierarchie
- ...

Comment: I like the idea of using a library for this. The thought of building this from scratch is not appealing at all

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see from the example here and one on the code sandbox. Your JSON Looks like an [M-ary Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ary_tree).

```
    1
    |
   1.1 
    |
  1.1.1
  /   \
1.1.2 1.1.3
```

So, you need to use concepts of [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), or [BackTracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) That might take O(n) time complexity